# refactor linq operations to avoid duplicate similar code

Tags: c#, .net, linq, refactoring

I'm trying to simplify this piece of code where the only difference is that, if the `referenceDate.Hour` it's greater than 20, we should only take items larger than today. Otherwise, we take larger or equal items.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //todays date is 07/02
        //I have the daysToCut 10, 15, 20, 25
        //if my referenceDate.Hour is bigger than 8pm, than i want the next day to cut other than today
        //but if my referenceDate.Hour is less than 8pm, i want the next day to cut (regardless if it's today or not)
        
        int nextDayToTake = 0;
        var daysToCut = new List<int>{10, 15, 20, 25};
        var referenceDate = DateTime.Now; //output is 10 bc today is 07/02
        //var referenceDate = new DateTime(2023, 02, 10, 20, 00, 00); //output is 15 bc the date's day is 10 and hour equals 20pm
        
        if (referenceDate.Hour >= 20)
        {
            nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(x => x > referenceDate.Day) ? daysToCut.First(x => x > referenceDate.Day) : daysToCut.Min();
        }
        else
        {
            nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(x => x >= referenceDate.Day) ? daysToCut.First(x => x >= referenceDate.Day) : daysToCut.Min();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(nextDayToTake);
    }
}
```

I tried it with ternary operators only, but I still found it too complex to understand. Could you help me to refactor in a more elegant way?

```
var daysToCut = new List<int>{10, 15, 20, 25};
var referenceDate = DateTime.Now;
//var referenceDate = new DateTime(2023, 02, 10, 20, 00, 00);
        
var nextDayToTake = referenceDate.Hour >= 20 ? 
            daysToCut.Any(x => x > referenceDate.Day) ? daysToCut.First(x => x > referenceDate.Day) : daysToCut.Min() 
            : daysToCut.Any(x => x >= referenceDate.Day) ? daysToCut.First(x => x >= referenceDate.Day) : daysToCut.Min();

Console.WriteLine(nextDayToTake);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would aim for **isolating the most basic expressions that actually differ from each other** inside of each `if` loop, and creating logic based on those expressions.

Inside your `if`/`else`,

```
if (referenceDate.Hour >= 20)
{
    nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(x => x > referenceDate.Day)
        ? daysToCut.First(x => x > referenceDate.Day)
        : daysToCut.Min();
}
else
{
    nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(x => x >= referenceDate.Day)
        ? daysToCut.First(x => x >= referenceDate.Day)
        : daysToCut.Min();
}
```

the **differing expressions** are the following emphasized ones:

> nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(**x => x > referenceDate.Day**)
>        ? daysToCut.First(**x => x > referenceDate.Day**)
>        : daysToCut.Min();

> nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(**x => x >= referenceDate.Day**)
>        ? daysToCut.First(**x => x >= referenceDate.Day**)
>        : daysToCut.Min();

(The `>` and `>=` operators are the only actually differing *parts* in these expressions, but I will work with the whole expressions.)

I will name these expressions **predicates**, seeing as *predicate* is an established name of the input parameter of the [`Enumerable.Any()` overload you are using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-any-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean)))).

To generalize a little, we could name the first predicate **predicate A**, and the second predicate **predicate B**:

> nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(**predicate A**)
>        ? daysToCut.First(**predicate A**)
>        : daysToCut.Min();

> nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(**predicate B**)
>        ? daysToCut.First(**predicate B**)
>        : daysToCut.Min();

Now, **predicate A** and **predicate B** are both of the same data type; they are both a function that takes an `int` (`x`) as an input parameter and returns a `bool` value (based on `x` being compared to `referenceDate.Day`). The data type of both predicates is hence [`Func<int, bool>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-7.0).

The predicates can be defined as follows:

```
Func<int, bool> predicateA = x => x > referenceDate.Day;
Func<int, bool> predicateB = x => x >= referenceDate.Day;
```

(For clarity, I'd prefer to name the input variable something more descriptive:)

```
Func<int, bool> predicateA = dayInMonth => dayInMonth > referenceDate.Day;
Func<int, bool> predicateB = dayInMonth => dayInMonth >= referenceDate.Day;
```

Seeing as **predicate A** and **predicate B** share data type, we could create one single **predicate** variable and assign whichever of **predicate A** and **predicate B** is relevant. The single **predicate** would then be used in the exact same manner:

> nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(**predicate**)
>        ? daysToCut.First(**predicate**)
>        : daysToCut.Min();

The condition for assigning the correct predicate is the one you have provided in your original code:

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = referenceDate.Hour >= 20 ? predicateA : predicateB;
```

(You would possibly want to create a helper variable, for readability:)

```
var conditionForA = referenceDate.Hour >= 20;

Func<int, bool> predicate = conditionForA ? predicateA : predicateB;
```

Now, you can simply use your **predicate** in your calculation of `nextDayToTake`. No `if` loop or code duplication needed.

```
var nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(predicate)
    ? daysToCut.First(predicate)
    : daysToCut.Min();
```

---

Putting everything together, the implementation could look something along the lines of:

```
var daysToCut = new List<int> { 10, 15, 20, 25 };

var referenceDate = DateTime.Now;

var conditionForA = referenceDate.Hour >= 20;

Func<int, bool> predicateA = dayInMonth => dayInMonth > referenceDate.Day;
Func<int, bool> predicateB = dayInMonth => dayInMonth >= referenceDate.Day;

Func<int, bool> predicate = conditionForA ? predicateA : predicateB;

var nextDayToTake = daysToCut.Any(predicate) ? daysToCut.First(predicate) : daysToCut.Min();
```

**Note:**
I would strongly suggest that you rename **conditionForA**, **predicateA** and **predicateB** to something more descriptive. I don't quite understand the logic in your code, so I have not made an attempt to create suitable variable names myself.

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3jO6je).

Answer (score 0):

use

var referenceDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4).Day;

take items larger than or equal to.